# Get date format (American or Australian) on a domain controller for Active Directory Script

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have a VBScript to extract users on a domain that are between certain dates so I can modify their accounts.

sometimes, I notice when I extend the expiry date it reverses the date I set (In Australian format dd/mm/yyyy) to American format....

how should I over come this, should I be checking the domain controller date format - if so, how can I get that info from the domain controller?

or is their a code like FORMAT in VBA...so i can set the date 'my way' ....maybe I should convert everything to VBA..

This is the basics of my code...

```
 Start_Date = 01/08/2014 ' 1st august 2014
 Days       = 28/08/2014 '28th august 2014

 Combined_Date = DateAdd("d", Days, Start_Date)
 Start_Date    = DateAdd("n", lngBias, Start_Date)
 Combined_Date = DateAdd("n", lngBias, Combined_Date)
 lngSeconds1   = DateDiff("s", #1/1/1601#, Start_Date)
 lngSeconds2   = DateDiff("s", #1/1/1601#, Combined_Date)
 str64Bit1     = CStr(lngSeconds1) & "0000000"
 str64Bit2     = CStr(lngSeconds2) & "0000000"

'##############################################################

 Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
 strDomain      = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

' my filter to get users that expiry between dates that are not disabled.
 SearchBy       = "<LDAP://" & strDomain & ">;" & _
 "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(accountExpires>=" & _
  str64Bit1 & ")(accountExpires<=" & str64Bit2 & ")(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)));" & _
 "distinguishedname;subtree"

 Set objConnection                    = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objConnection.Provider               = "ADsDSOObject"
 objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set objCommand                       = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objCommand.ActiveConnection      = objConnection
 objCommand.Properties("Page Size")   = 100000
 objCommand.Properties("Timeout")     = 300
 objCommand.Properties("Size Limit")  = 750000
 objCommand.CommandText               = SearchBy
 Set objRecordSet                     = objCommand.Execute
 objRecordSet.MoveFirst

 Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
  objUserOU  = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedname").Value
  Set myUser = GetObject ("LDAP://" & objUserOU)


   Wscript.Echo myUser.SamAccountName
   Wscript.Echo myUser.DisplayName
   Wscript.Echo myUser.AccountExpirationDate

  Err.clear
  objRecordSet.MoveNext
 Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need not know culture, language or regional setting of script-running machine neither data-holding server, because of internal representation of date/time values does not depend on those...

For date/time entry use either date literal, i.e. a string representing a date and/or time enclosed in hash signs (#), either `DateSerial` / `TimeSerial` function, or (not recommended) string. Next `Start_Date` variable entries are all equivalent:

```
Dim Start_Date, Days, Combined_Date
 'If Start_Date should be "1st august 2014"
 'String (not recommended)   
 Start_Date = "1/8/2014"
 'Literal
 Start_Date = #2014-08-01#  ' ISO format
 Start_Date = #01-Aug-2014#
 Start_Date = #Aug/1/2014#
 Start_Date = #8/1/2014#
 Start_Date = #8-1-2014#
 'DateSerial() function
 Start_Date = DateSerial( 2014, 8, 1)
```

Next two-lines code snippet should be as follows:

```
 Days          = 27
 Combined_Date = DateAdd("d", Days, Start_Date)  '28th august 2014
```

For output we'd use `FormatDateTime` function with appropriate (built into VBScript) date format constants:

```
  Wscript.Echo FormatDateTime( Start_Date, vbGeneralDate)
  Wscript.Echo FormatDateTime( Start_Date, vbLongDate)
  Wscript.Echo FormatDateTime( Start_Date, vbShortDate)
```

And - I'm afraid - `myUser.AccountExpirationDate` is not vbscript datetime variant, hence you may not apply `FormatDateTime()` function on it!